# Pytorch - TypeError: 'torch.Size' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, pytorch

Hi I am training a PyTorch model and occurred this error:

`----> 5     for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):`

`TypeError: 'torch.Size' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Not sure what this error means.

You can find my code here :

```
model.train()
for epoch in range(10):
    running_loss = 0

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):

        inputs, labels = data

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if i % 2000 == 0:
          print (loss.item())
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print ('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch, i, running_loss/ 1000))
            running_loss = 0

torch.save(model, 'FeatureNet.pkl')
```

---

### Update

This is the codeblock for DataLoader. I am using a customized dataloader and datasets, which `x` are pictures with size (1025, 16) and `y` are one-hot encoded vectors for classification.

`x_train.shape` = (1100, 1025, 16)

`y_train.shape` = (1100, 10)

```
clean_dir = '/home/tk/Documents/clean/' 
mix_dir = '/home/tk/Documents/mix/' 
clean_label_dir = '/home/tk/Documents/clean_labels/' 
mix_label_dir = '/home/tk/Documents/mix_labels/' 

class MSourceDataSet(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, clean_dir, mix_dir, clean_label_dir, mix_label_dir):

        with open(clean_dir + 'clean0.json') as f:
            clean0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))

        with open(mix_dir + 'mix0.json') as f:
            mix0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))

        with open(clean_label_dir + 'clean_label0.json') as f:
            clean_label0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))


        with open(mix_label_dir + 'mix_label0.json') as f:
            mix_label0 = torch.Tensor(json.load(f))


        self.spec = torch.cat([clean0, mix0], 0)
        self.label = torch.cat([clean_label0, mix_label0], 0)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.spec.shape


    def __getitem__(self, index): 

        spec = self.spec[index]
        label = self.label[index]
        return spec, label
```

### **getitem**

```
a, b = trainset.__getitem__(1000)
print (a.shape)
print (b.shape)
```

a.shape = `torch.Size([1025, 16])`;
b.shape = `torch.Size([10])`

### Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3bd71e5c00e1> in <module>()
      3     running_loss = 0
      4 
----> 5     for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
      6 
      7         inputs, labels = data

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    311     def __next__(self):
    312         if self.num_workers == 0:  # same-process loading
--> 313             indices = next(self.sample_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
    314             batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
    315             if self.pin_memory:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __iter__(self)
    136     def __iter__(self):
    137         batch = []
--> 138         for idx in self.sampler:
    139             batch.append(idx)
    140             if len(batch) == self.batch_size:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __iter__(self)
     32 
     33     def __iter__(self):
---> 34         return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))
     35 
     36     def __len__(self):

TypeError: 'torch.Size' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the `__len__` function. You cannot use the `shape` as return value.

Here is an example for illustration:

```
import torch
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape

myFoo = Foo(data=torch.rand(10, 20))
print(len(myFoo))
```

Will raise exactly the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-285-e97aace2f622> in <module>
      7 
      8 myFoo = Foo(data=torch.rand(10, 20))
----> 9 print(len(myFoo))

TypeError: 'torch.Size' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Since shape represents a `torch.Size` tuple:

```
print(myFoo.data.shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([10, 20])
```

So you have to decide which dimension you want to hand over to `__len__`, for example the first dimension:

```
import torch
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0] # choosing first dimension for len

myFoo = Foo(data=torch.rand(10, 20))
print(len(myFoo))
# prints 10
```

Works fine and returns `10`. Of course you can also choose any other dimension of your input, but you have to choose one.

So in your code of your `MSourceDataSet` you have to change your `__len__` function to for example:

```
def __len__(self):
    return self.spec.shape[0] # as said of course you can also choose other dimensions
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: size(0) should be the same as shape[0] right?